Make Pixel Launcher render more text in icons/shortcuts labels
I've got Google Pixel 6 Pro with the default launcher. I'm kind of fine with it. For whatever design "solution", this launcher trims icon/shortcut labels it considers "out of bounds" just cutting off most of the text replacing all of it with ellipsis. For example, what it considers "out of bounds":

Advanced Root Checker becomes Advanced Root ...
Air Raid Alert Map of Ukraine becomes Air Raid Alert... (a web page shortcut added to the home screen from Firefox)

Some answers recommend absolutely a useless way to fix it: changing the default system-wide font size should not be used to configure the apps in general (I mean, why would changing the font size affect behavior of a particular launcher?) + increasing/decreasing the font size doesn't disable label trimming.
I'm looking for a way to either make it allow wider text labels or render the text labels at least in two rows. Any real solution would be appreciated: a Pixel Launcher fork, a module for Magisk/LSPosed/XPL-EX, whatever.
